# (python) issue bash commands from within python script (alla perl system($cmd))

Tags: python, bash

Within a python script, I want to issue a command. In perl, I could define a command, save it as a variable (here, `$cmd`) then type `system($cmd)` and then the command is executed.

How can i do that in python?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You *can* use [`os.system()`](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html#replacing-os-system), but prefer [`subprocess`](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html) instead.

Answer (score 1):

Another good choice is "commands" module: http://docs.python.org/library/commands.html.

Answer (score 0):

you can use os.system(), or the newer subprocess module. Other possible alternatives (for older Python versions) include [these](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html#process-management). (eg os.spawn*,os.popen*,etc)

Lastly, try using Python's modules to do operating system stuff instead of calling external commands if possible, unless its a third party tool you are executing and Python doesn't have the api.